# Why songs in the music folder are not showing up in music player?

Tags: music

I copied some songs from my windows system to windows 535 phone. The songs shows up in the files folder, but does not show up in music player, except for one song? How do I fix this.

Comment: Where on your phone did you copy the files to from your PC? How did you copy the files - did you use the Windows Phone app on Windows 8.x, via Explorer, or something else?

Comment: How long have you waited? Leave the music app running for a while and they should appear. When I copied music to the SD card, it took about half an hour before they all appeared (I have a lot of music).

Comment: Welcome to the world of Windows Phone community! Providing more details such as OS version of your windows, the music app that you're running, how exactly you copied music would give a proper and to the point solution for your problem. If your issue is solved, you're welcome to provide it as an answer, so that it will help the community.