# how to play music in nokia lumia 530

Tags: music

I using Nokia Lumia 530.i download songs in my sd card but it does not shows any music on the music files
But music saved in my sd card what can i do for hear the songs?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/11433/106

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the downloaded music is in the Music library. It can either be SDCard->Music or Phone->Music.

If not, you can easily move the music file using the built-in Files app.